# incremental archive backup similar to rsnapshot

Tags: debian, backup, rsnapshot

I am looking for a similar tool like rsnapshot, capable of doing incremental backups and easy viewing of different backup versions (=easy unpacking of all increments of a specific backup or viewing of single files without unpacking them all).

I sadly cannot use rsnapshot because my backup-provider does not support hard-links.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What might work is that you mount your backup space via cifs and create a large image file with a hardlink capable filesystem on it and then mount this image via the loopback device as a target for rsnapshot.

Comment: This seems like a pretty good idea. But is this a commonly-used technique and does it involve risks?

Comment: Well it works somehow but i am getting various Input/Output Errors. Any ideas?

Comment: I finally got it! I was trying to back up a ext4 system to a ext2 backup filesystem. At all, your idea seems to work pretty well apart from it being pretty slow but that's okay at the moment. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with `rsnapshot` but `rdiff-backup` might do the job... See http://www.nongnu.org/rdiff-backup/examples.html  for basic examples...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a lowtech equivalent to rsnapshot : https://github.com/JacquelinCharbonnel/rocknroll.git, but hard-links support are needed too.